# what is the "~/.local" and can I delete it?

Tags: filesystems

`/home/user/.local` is kinda big (~5.6Gb on debian squeeze and 3.7 on ubuntu 12.04) for me, so, can I delete it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`~/.local` – or more precisely, `~/.local/share` – is where XDG-compliant programs store user data (e.g., fonts, mail messages) according to the [XDG Base Directory specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

The `~/.local` folder also contains `share/Trash`, which is your [trash bin](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html). Everything you put in there of course takes up space. I assume this is the most likely cause of disk usage.

Check how much space it takes up with:

```
du -hs ~/.local/share/Trash
```

If you don't need to keep items in the trash, empty it through your file manager or just delete everything in `share/Trash` with:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash
```

Comment: can we configure custom make/installs to use it instead of /usr/local?

Comment: Refer to [Ignacio's answer](https://superuser.com/a/473631/762617) if you are looking to delete the whole .local directory and not just Trash sub-directory

Answer (score 8):

It's the new location for user-specific, application-specific data. Removing it will not affect the system as a whole, but it *will* erase a large amount of user data.

Comment: pip installs applications there , not just app specific data.